# Controlling the number of outputs for mapreduce partitioned output

Tags: scala, mapreduce, scoobi, bigdata

I have a huge input data set (~3 Tb) which I reprocess using Scala/Scoobi and write into partitioned output. The output has 54  partitions, but the total size of the data after reprocessing and enrichment is more than 2x the size of the input data.

As a result of reprocessing i get a DList[(String,String)], where the first string is partition key (i.e. "year=2016/month=1/day=14") and the second String is some data (ie "val1^val2^val3"). Before writing this DList to hdfs i do some grouping in order to reduce the ammount of ouput files in each partition:

```
out
.groupBy(r => r._1)
.mapFlatten(r => r._2)
.toPartitionedTextFile("outputPath/", identity, overwrite = true)
.persist
```

which basically sorts the output by key before writing it to a file. However with this approach the size of data under some reducers reaches 400 Gb and they take hours to process.

If i don't do groupBy with mapFlatten to sort data before writing it i get 65 000 output files under my 54 partitions, some of which < 1Kb in size. I don't understand how come there are so many files if i only have a bit more than 3000 reducers for this job?

I also have set the reduce.bytes parameter to 1000000000, but i don't see it have any effect on the processing...

Is there a way to forse MR to split the 400 Gb reducers while processing? I don't mind having even 100 output files under each partition, but 2000 per partition are too many...